# Click event won't trigger?

Tags: c++

When the screens shows, there is one squere when ckicking on the square, it should create 4 squares.
First i made the explosion. This is made in the drawExplosion but when i try to change the enum class of g_status to clicked nothing happens. There is no side effect happening. Normally 4 squares should appear on the side of the window. In the processMouseclicks it checks of the click is in the first square. But when i click the square nothing is drawn, only the clickstatus is changed.

````
#include "pch.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>

//Basic game functions
#pragma region gameFunctions                                            
void Start()
{
    // initialize game resources here
}

void Draw()
{
    ClearBackground();

    // Put your own draw statements here
    switch (g_Status) {
    case ClickStatus::notClicked: { 
        Rectf rect{ g_Center.x - g_SizeExplosion / 2, g_Center.y - g_SizeExplosion / 2, g_SizeExplosion, g_SizeExplosion };
        SetColor(0, 0, 1);
        FillRect(rect);
        std::cout << (int)g_Status;
        break;
    }
    case ClickStatus::clicked: {
        DrawExplosion();
        break;
    }
    }


}

void Update(float elapsedSec)
{

}

void End()
{
    // free game resources here
}
#pragma endregion gameFunctions

//Keyboard and mouse input handling
#pragma region inputHandling                                            
void OnKeyDownEvent(SDL_Keycode key)
{

}

void OnKeyUpEvent(SDL_Keycode key)
{

}

void OnMouseMotionEvent(const SDL_MouseMotionEvent& e)
{

}

void OnMouseDownEvent(const SDL_MouseButtonEvent& e)
{
}

void OnMouseUpEvent(const SDL_MouseButtonEvent& e)
{

    ProcessMouseClick();

}
#pragma endregion inputHandling

#pragma region ownDefinitions
// Initialize your own variables here

// Define your own functions here

void DrawExplosion() {

    Rectf rect{ g_Center.x - g_SizeExplosion / 2, g_Center.y - g_SizeExplosion / 2, g_SizeExplosion, g_SizeExplosion };
    SetColor(0, 0, 0);
    FillRect(rect);

    SetColor(1, 0, 0);

    FillRect(g_XBackWards - g_SizeExplosion / 2, g_YForwards - g_SizeExplosion / 2, g_SizeExplosion, g_SizeExplosion);
    FillRect(g_XForwards - g_SizeExplosion / 2, g_YBackWards - g_SizeExplosion / 2, g_SizeExplosion, g_SizeExplosion);
    FillRect(g_XBackWards - g_SizeExplosion / 2, g_YBackWards - g_SizeExplosion / 2, g_SizeExplosion, g_SizeExplosion);
    FillRect(g_YForwards - g_SizeExplosion / 2, g_YForwards - g_SizeExplosion / 2, g_SizeExplosion, g_SizeExplosion);

    g_XForwards++;
    g_YForwards++;
    g_XBackWards--;
    g_YBackWards--;

    if (g_XForwards == g_WindowWidth) {
        g_XForwards = g_Center.x;
        g_YForwards = g_Center.y;
        g_XBackWards = g_Center.x;
        g_YBackWards = g_Center.y;
        
    }

    g_Status = ClickStatus::notClicked;
}

void ProcessMouseClick() {

    Point2f mouseClick{};
    //Event handler
    SDL_Event e;
    //Main loop flag
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
        {
            //User requests quit
            switch (e.type)
            {
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP: {
                if (e.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
                    mouseClick.x = float(e.button.x);
                    mouseClick.y = g_WindowHeight - e.button.y;

                    Point2f bottomRect{ (g_Center.x - g_SizeExplosion / 2),(g_Center.y - g_SizeExplosion / 2) }
                    , topSquare{ (g_Center.x + g_SizeExplosion / 2),(g_Center.y + g_SizeExplosion / 2) };
                    if (mouseClick.x >= bottomRect.x && mouseClick.x <= topSquare.x &&
                        mouseClick.y >= bottomRect.y && mouseClick.y <= topSquare.y)
                    {
            
                        std::cout << "clicked";
                        g_Status = ClickStatus::clicked;
                        std::cout << (int)g_Status;
                    }
                    
                }

            }
            }
        }
    }
}
#pragma endregion ownDefinitions
```
````

Comment: "nothing happens"? Do you mean that the variable value doesn't change, or that the change does not have the side effect that you expect?

Comment: there is no side effect happening. Normally 4 squares should appear on the side of the window.

Comment: How/when is the OnMouseUpEvent() function called? Do you have another SDL_PollEvent() event-handling loop somewhere else in your code that executes that function?